# Selenium Grid session terminated because SO_Timeout

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

From C# client, my driver variable returns "Selenium Grid session terminated because SO_Timeout" after 2 seconds. I'm looking for a way to increase that from SE Grid server since it looks like I need to increase the timeout from Selenium Node.

Thanks for helping with this issue.

Comment: What are the values for different timeouts that you have configured in your Grid setup ? See here (https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2#configuring-timeouts-version-221-required) for more information

Comment: my json config:

{
  "host": null,
  "port": 80,
  "newSessionWaitTimeout": -1,
  "servlets": [],
  "prioritizer":  null,
  "capabilityMatcher": "org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher",
  "throwOnCapabilityNotPresent": true,
  "nodePolling": 5000,
  "cleanUpCycle": 5000,
  "browserTimeout": 60000,
  "maxSession": 5,
  "jettyMaxThreads": -1
}

is there a way to increase the timeout from hub to give the client more time?

Answer (score 0):

resolved the problem.

I did not setup timeout properly.
It should be "timeout" parameter instead of "browser_timeout" for this regard.

inside the json, it is in millisecond and from command line, it is in second measurement.

I changed the json timeout so it will cover the 30 seconds timeout parameter I passed from the Selenium client driver.

The json looks like this:

{ "host": null, 
"port": 80, 
"newSessionWaitTimeout": -1, 
"servlets": [], 
"prioritizer": null, 
"capabilityMatcher": 
"org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher", "throwOnCapabilityNotPresent": true, 
"nodePolling": 5000, 
"cleanUpCycle": 5000, 
"browserTimeout": 60000, 
"timeout":50000, 
"maxSession": 5, 
"jettyMaxThreads": -1 }

Thank you Krishnan for pointing me out the reference page.

Buu